# How to redirect to another page when using preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

Can someone help me to redirect to another page(in my case, redirect to "cart page"). Im using preventDefault() to avoid from go to the other page before validate but after i use preventDefault(), even after the validation, im still on the same page. PLEASE HELP ME:(

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const password = document.getElementById('password');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
e.preventDefault();

checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
// trim to remove the whitespaces
const emailValue = email.value.trim();
const passwordValue = password.value.trim();


if(emailValue === '') {
setErrorFor(email, 'This field is required');
} else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
setErrorFor(email, 'Not a valid email');
} else {
setSuccessFor(email);
}

if(passwordValue === '') {
setErrorFor(password, 'This field is required');
} else {
setSuccessFor(password);
}


function setErrorFor(input, message) {
const formValidate = input.parentElement;
const small = formValidate.querySelector('small');
formValidate.className = 'form-validate error';
small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
const formValidate = input.parentElement;
formValidate.className = 'form-validate success';
}

function isEmail(email) {
return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}
}

  </script>
```

```html
<form id="form" action="cart.html" method="get">
                <div class="form-validate">
                  <label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label>
                  <input class="form-input" id="email" type="text">
                        <small>Error message</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-validate">
                  <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
                  <input class="form-input" id="password" type="password">
                        <small>Error message</small>
                </div>
<div class="form-validate text-center">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-sign-in-alt me-2"></i> Log in</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store whether the form is valid in a variable named `isValid` and set it to `false` in your `if` statements should one of the fields be invalid.

After validation, check whether `isValid` is true. If it is, submit the form with `form.submit()`:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const password = document.getElementById('password');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
  // trim to remove the whitespaces
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
  var isValid = true;

  if (emailValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(email, 'This field is required');
    isValid = false;
  } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
    setErrorFor(email, 'Not a valid email');
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(email);
  }

  if (passwordValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(password, 'This field is required');
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(password);
  }

  if (isValid) {
    form.submit();
  }

  function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formValidate = input.parentElement;
    const small = formValidate.querySelector('small');
    formValidate.className = 'form-validate error';
    small.innerText = message;
  }

  function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formValidate = input.parentElement;
    formValidate.className = 'form-validate success';
  }

  function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="cart.html" method="get">
  <div class="form-validate">
    <label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="form-input" id="email" type="text">
    <small>Error message</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-validate">
    <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
    <input class="form-input" id="password" type="password">
    <small>Error message</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-validate text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-sign-in-alt me-2"></i> Log in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```